# Fastest way to get multiple rows using npgsql

Tags: c#, npgsql

I have a following code with List of guids and I need to get all corresponding items from database:

```
var guids = new List<string>()
{
    "1HFAoQchL1NB9Tc5wJLYHm",
    "1OLd2nLP92c87kmkHaMAtO",
    "2FwmMnAX98sg537nfo$S39",
    "38pd0XqUvEvA8nrnF$3vvZ",
    "0iqYqWKBvC_x62wk0jcKW3",
    "0njEfI2BzDEeQpiOo5S18q",
    "0chMA4Bgf9nxnq2i1gG9Fb",
    "3TrnV9L79FfBz0ni6_bJ9N"
};
foreach (var gd in guids)
{
    MemoryStream stream = null;
    using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string sQL = $"SELECT geometricaldata FROM entities WHERE guid= '{gd}'";
        using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand(sQL, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    stream = new MemoryStream((byte[])reader[0]);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do I really need to do this in a loop one by one or it would be better to batch SELECT statements? Or maybe there is another way how to get multiple rows with one query that I don't know of?

Comment: Why do you use `$"...guid = ..."`? You can use `$"...guid IN ({String.Join(",", guids.Select(item => $"'{item}'")})"` and query will return all matching records by one DB call.

Comment: _"Fastest way...."_ - _["Performance questions are on topic if they include a specific area of focus for improvement, can be answered with facts/citations (like specific timings/memory analysis), and such an answer would not be an unreasonable length (e.g. you could write an entire book on the topic)."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412875/what-makes-a-good-performance-question-on-so#comment878044_412875)_, Henry Ecker.

Comment: @Roman Oh, yes! This is exactly what I wanted to achieve. I did not know of such a way! Thank you very much! If you post this this as an answer, I will gladly accept it!

Comment: The suggestion above with IN means you execute a different SQL for each GUID value set, which prevents usage of prepared statements (really important for perf).

Comment: It's better to have a single array-of-GUIDs parameter, and use `WHERE guid = ANY (@arrayParam)`.